# API to access Google Doc "Email Notification settings"

Tags: google-workspace

We have hundreds of business documents, and when a user makes a suggested edit or comment it's the manager's responsibility to review and approve/reject.

Google offers a feature to receive an email notification when a comment is made or suggested edit made(otherwise easy for managers to loose track or not know about suggested edits/comments), and we'd like to turn this on for managers but manually doing this for hundreds of documents is a maintenance nightmare. Is there an API that would allow us programmatically set this field, or even read it.

If there are no APIs is there some other recommended work flow such that employees can suggest improvements and managers will be proactively notified so they can approve/reject the suggestion(ISO 9001 Control of Documents/Records)?

PS I wrote some [scripts to poll documents for open comments/suggestion](https://github.com/dawydiuk/SharedDriveFilesCommentsOrSuggestions), but we'd prefer to be proactively notified.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a program to watch changes in files by using the [SuggestionsViewMode](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/suggestions#python). You need to fetch the entire document content and then look through it for [suggestions](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#suggestionsviewmode).

```
result = service.documents().get(documentId=DOCUMENT_ID, suggestion_mode=SUGGEST_MODE).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume by the previous response that there is not a way to change notification settings for a doc via API?

I actually have sort of the opposite problem of the OP, where I am generating lots of documents for a shared drive via automations. These docs are used by our team, but aren't generally relevant to me. Because my account is the one generating the docs, the notification setting defaults to "All comments and tasks".

It would be great if I could update my automation to change the notification setting to "Comments and tasks for you" after creating the doc. I'd appreciate any suggestions.